# Any faster ways of searching for items from one list in another?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with filenames. Names from the second list contain names from the first one, such as:

```
lst1 = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
lst2 = ['file2_processed', 'file1_processed', 'file3_processed']
```

Filenames in `lst2` are not in the same order as in `lst1`, that's the problem.

I need to get a list with pairs of `lst1` entries and respective `lst2` entries, such as:

```
lst3 = [['file1', 'file1_processed'],
        ['file2', 'file2_processed'],
        ['file3', 'file3_processed']]
```

All I have come up with is this function:

```
def pairs(a, b):
    c = []
    for wa in a:
        for wb in b:
            if wa in wb:
                c.append([wa, wb])
    return c
```

But this one is really slow on huge lists, so I'm here to ask: are there any faster ways to perform this operation?

Comment: the list would be empty, because `file1.txt` is not in `file1_processed.txt`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This code has some pretty strong code smells. Have you considered using classes to store your state, instead of having to do string parsing?

Comment: Are you always trying to match `<name>_processed.txt` in `lst2` for a file `<name>.txt` in `lst1`? Is it always just as simple as appending a `_processed`? How is the relation between those lists? Is there a processed file for each file in `lst1`? Or just for some? Are there processed files for files that are *not* in `lst1`? You really need to add more information about [your actual problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); otherwise I would assume that I can just generate `lst2` from `lst1` in a single pass.

Comment: of course, I don't do a plain search, I use os.path.splitext. this function is just a basic interpretation of what i actually do.

Comment: Then provide more information.

Comment: Given the information we have, what you've done is basically as efficient as it gets.  However, knowing how you build these lists in the first place is very important, as there might be a trivial optimization to apply at that stage that would make this a much more efficient operation.

Comment: Assuming the names in list1 are always a prefix of the names in list2, you should use `wa.startswith(wb)` instead of `wa in wb`. Some quick measurements show that it's about twice as fast, at least on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how much it would slow it down, but a simple and easy to understand way of doing it would be:

```
def pair(a,b): 
    c = ''.join(b.split('_processed'))
    return a == c
lst3 = [[x,y] for x in lst1 for y in lst2 if pair(x,y)]
```

Probably a bit slower of an implementation than other answers though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the *creation* of a `O(n^2)` list, then I suggest you to use iterators from the `itertools` module:

```
import itertools as it

def parse(haystack, needle):
    return (x for x in it.product(haystack, needle) where x[1] in x[0])
```

Another possible optimization: if the pattern is always finding `<x>` into `<x>_processed`, then instead of using the `in` operator, you may want to call the `str.startwiths` method:

```
return (x for x in it.product(haystack, needle) where x[0].startswith(x[1]))
```

Of course the `.txt` would be in the way...

Is the order meaningful? If not you might want to sort the two lists and search only the relevant part of the haystack.

Comment: Using itertools will not magically make a quadratic computation non-quadratic. You just added some flavor on top to hide the two loops. And the result list will be equally large for large input lists (per definition of the desired result list).

Comment: @poke, correct, but it will get rid of a large output, as long as you don't put the result into another list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to roll it all in with a list comprehension, but otherwise do exactly as you've done. If you're comparing two sorted lists, there really isn't a faster algorithm than O(n^2). Note that if you have to make more than one of these, it's almost invariably faster to sort `lst2` and use `itertools.groupby` to group by prefix.

```
lst1 = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
lst2 = ['file2_processed.txt', 'file1_processed.txt', 'file3_processed.txt']

lst3 = [(prefix, [fullname for fullname in lst2 if fullname.startswith(prefix)]) for
        prefix in lst1]
```

As I mentioned above, if you're building more than one of these, then `itertools.groupby` might be better:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst1_set = set(lst1)  # faster lookups
lst2.sort()  # groupby must operate on a sorted list
lst3 = [(prefix, values) for prefix,values in groupby(
    lst2, lambda s: s.split('_')[0]) if prefix in lst1_set
```

In fact that example illuminates a different procedure that might work better for you:

```
lst1_set = set(lst1)  # set lookups are O(1)
lst3 = []
for s in lst2:
    prefix = s.split("_")[0]
    if prefix in lst1_set:
        lst3.append((prefix, s))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Without* (pardon me) attempting to write actual Python code to demonstrate my idea, another good strategy to apply in situations like this is to use associative arrays.  (i.e. "dictionaries.")

First, loop through `lst1` creating a dummy entry in the dictionary for every key found there.

Now, separately, loop through `lst2`. Split the string `file2_processed` into `file2` and `processed`.  Now, see if the first part ("file2") is in the dictionary.  *(If not, why not?)* Store the second part ("processed") into that dictionary-entry slot.

A Python dictionary is specifically designed to produce the (one) value that's associated with any key ... very quickly ... or to conclude that such an entry does not exist.  It's generally-speaking a very good strategy for avoiding searches, in almost any programming language.

You can then iterate over all of the `keys` in the dictionary, or over "the keys and their associated values," to produce the final result.  Note that the keys will *not* be produced in any particular sequence.